# Many warnings in Spark 2.3 with spark.read.json; subclasses resulted in no possible candidates

Tags: json, apache-spark

I know we can start spark-shell with the logs set to error but is there an explanation for these warnings? The first few warnings are ok as the path of the identical plugin warnings follow the symbolic link to /usr/local/bin/spark.

```
scala> val people = spark.read.json("/path/to/people.json").show
18/11/12 09:41:33 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/usr/local/bin/spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/usr/local/share/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
18/11/12 09:41:33 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/usr/local/bin/spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/usr/local/share/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
18/11/12 09:41:37 WARN Query: Query for candidates of org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MPartitionColumnStatistics and subclasses resulted in no possible candidates
Cannot add `SDS`.`SD_ID` as referenced FK column for `TBLS`
org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusException: Cannot add `SDS`.`SD_ID` as referenced FK column for `TBLS`
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.key.ForeignKey.setColumn(ForeignKey.java:232)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.key.ForeignKey.addColumn(ForeignKey.java:207)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.table.TableImpl.getExistingForeignKeys(TableImpl.java:1057)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
18/11/12 09:41:40 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
```